# subcategory not showing on admin panel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm editing a Laravel 4.3 site and I have a db table called categories which has the following fields:

id
parent_id
name
I'm trying to output a list in my view of categories, and their subcategories:

Category
Another Category
Subcat
Subcat
Subcat
I'm not really sure of the best way of achieving this and hoping someone can help point me in the right direction :-)

this is my controller

public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    $this->validate($request, [

        'name' =>'required'

    ]);




    $category= new Category;

    $category= Category::with('children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();

    $category->name =$request->name;

    $category->save();}
```

Comment: You've posted the code to store the category, post your code that you tried to get the categories and subcategories.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? `Category::with('children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get()`, because if the parent it null how the children will be there?

Comment: What are you trying to archive? Are you trying to store the categories and retrieve the categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this would help you

Method to store the data:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' =>'required',
        'parent_id' => 'nullable|exists:category,id', //This will check the parent availability
    ]);


    $category= new Category;

    if ($request->has('parent_id')) {
        $category->parent_id =$request->parent_id;
    }

    $category->name =$request->name;
    $category->save();

    return $category;
}
```

Method to retrieve all data:

```
public function index() {
    $categories = Category::with('children')->all();

    return $categories;
}
```

Method to get category by id :

```
public function categoryById(Category $category) {
    $category = Category::with('children')->where('id', $category->id)->first();

    return $category;
}
```

Comment: try to print the value inside index method before return `dd($categories);`

Comment: @user10945543 ok, if it solved your problem mark this answer as accepted and make up vote :)

Comment: yes, When I am adding the category of subcategory it's has created with the help of parent_id but in my index it's showing like 1 home->1.1.-home1->1.2-home2 2 peole 3 contact and then (home 1 home 2) again repeat in category index and same adding in my localhost as it should be shown under home->home1 home2

Comment: Controller public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // dd($request->all());
        $this->validate($request, [

            'name' =>'required',
            'parent_id' => 'required|numeric', //This will check the parent availability how about top level ? where id is 0?

        ]);

        Category::create([
            'name'=>$request->name,


            'parent_id'=>$request->parent_id
        ]);

        Session::flash('success', 'Category has created successfully');
        return redirect()->back();

    }

Comment: create.blade.php--  <select name="parent_id" id="parent_id">
                                                        <option value="0">Create New Menu</option>
                                                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                                                            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>

Comment: @user10945543 I don't understand what's not working here, because you have assigned parent category as `Home` for sub categories `Home1` and `Home2`, so it'll show like this `Home->Home1` and `Home->Home2` what is wrong in it?

Comment: yes, it's showing under Home->Home1 and Home->Home2 ans also showing in menu bar like (repeat in category also)Home, contact, people, Home1, Home2

Comment: then you should add `->whereNull('parent_id')` on `index` method like `Category::with('children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get()`

Comment: $menu= Category::with('children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();


        return view ('admin.categories.index')->with('categories',$menu)->with('categories', Category::all()); using this but still on same page